# How to execute external API calls with React + Express on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I’m still fairly new to full stack development and I’ve been stuck for days. I could really use some help from anyone who is familiar with React + Express + External API projects. Right now I still have my frontend and backend working concurrently and works fine on my local machine,

https://mernaddonsapp.herokuapp.com

the login and register are working with connected to mongodb alas on heroku but the external api is not working.

I've tried with heroku local, which I think runs the code on heroku locally, and everything works just fine. As for my client I served the files locally with "yarn build" and then "serve -d build" and it works.
but when I deployed the mern app to heroku I get no data sent to the front end from the external api in the back end.

this is the back end code in express

```
router.get('/filterByValue', (req, res) => {
    let url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`;
    let search = req.query.search;

    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            var listofcountries = filterByValue(response.data, search);
            console.log(listofcountries);
            res.status(200).json(listofcountries);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

and this is the front end code in react

```
filtersearch = async (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/countries/filterByValue/?search=${this.state.s}`
            )
            this.setState({
                specificCountry: response.data
            })
            this.props.history.push('/FilterListOfCountries', { response: this.state.specificCountry })
            console.log(response)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
            alert(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check your heroku logs, it should show you what is failing ...

Comment: @BARNOWL Hi thank for your message this is what I got 

```2020-07-18T04:58:40.499064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/countries/search" host=mernaddonsapp.herokuapp.com request_id=1d8efee1-5cb9-40f8-a9ef-0d48533b3581 fwd="77.71.157.106" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3734 protocol=https```

Comment: This is what come back from the server when I console log it

```[Log] No data: – "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\"/><meta name=\"viewport…" (main.9d91452d.chunk.js, line 1) ```

Comment: go to your heroku logs, and execute the functionality that is causing the error. From there is should show. The logs that you provided doesn't give me any insight.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did

Comment: ok... and this works on your local ?

Comment: Yes it works fine on my local and when I run heroku local. but after I deployed it to heroku I am not getting the external api. this is the repo on github
https://github.com/Babarindeolanrewaju2/mongoose-express-react-node.git

Comment: 1) do you have a client react build 2) share your express server code, that shows the express listen thing 3)do you have a react client side .env ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218063/discussion-between-barnowl-and-a-harry).